# How to add custom translations

Tags: magento-1, localisation

Can any one help me to, Where i have to include translated text for German in which csv file have to include ?

Find the below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `Mage_CatalogSearch.csv` under german locale folder

Comment: Thanks for the response, i was tried in Mage_CatalogSearch.csv file but no luck.

Comment: After adding translation you require to refresh "Translations" cache.

Comment: Thanks, yes i did flush the cache but not effecting

Comment: Other translations are working but this one is not effecting

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 different methods to add or change a translations in Magento:

**1) Inline Translation :**

The translations will be placed in the database (core_translate table). You can enable the Inline Translation for frontend or backend separately. To do it: `System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Translate Inline`. Also, you can use the Inline Translation method to add a new translation to the Default Config (all stores) or to the specific store view.

**2) Theme translation :**

It allows you to add a translation only to a specific theme. All changes will be placed in the CSV file in this path: `app/design/{area}/{package}/{theme}/locale/{language_code}{country_code}/translate.csv`

**3) Module translations :**

This kind of translation is used for Default Config (all stores). It is stored within: `app/locale/{language_code}_{country_code}/{namespace}_{module}.csv`

**Wich one is better : ?**

- Inline Translation :

**Plus**: This method is easy and non-technical.

**Minus:** When you need to add a lot of changes, you have to be ready to spend considerably more time.

- Theme translation :

**Pluses** and **minuses** depend a lot on your needs: It can be applied just to the theme where changes are added. The best solution is to make changes only in a current theme. And the worst course of events is when you have several themes and you need to add the same changes to all of them.

- Module translation :

**Plus:** Adding a translation file to your own/core/ third party module is considered as a good method.

**Minus:** However, it is much more difficult than the Inline Translation.