# Magento Translation ver. 1.9.3.4

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, translate

I am trying to Translate this phrase: Search entire store here... that appears in the default Search Form.

So far I have tried adding it here:

`staging/app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/locale/pl_PL/translate.csv`

I have also added it

`here:/public_html/staging/app/locale/pl_PL/Mage_CatalogSearch.csv`

But still no luck. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I) To translate your word, it should have the **method translation** ! something like: `$this->__('Your word here')` or `Mage::helper('module')->__('Your word here');`. So check if you have well the translate method in your file.

II) You have 3 different methods to add or change a translations in Magento:

**1) Inline Translation :**

The translations will be placed in the database (core_translate table). You can enable the Inline Translation for frontend or backend separately. To do it: `System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Translate Inline`. Also, you can use the Inline Translation method to add a new translation to the Default Config (all stores) or to the specific store view.

**2) Theme translation :**

It allows you to add a translation only to a specific theme. All changes will be placed in the CSV file in this path: `app/design/{area}/{package}/{theme}/locale/{language_code}{country_code}/translate.csv`

**3) Module translations :**

This kind of translation is used for Default Config (all stores). It is stored within: `app/locale/{language_code}_{country_code}/{namespace}_{module}.csv`

For more [information](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178725/48355)

**EDIT:**

For the search module Go to `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml` for exemple and check if you have the translation method then translate it according my answer.

the **form.mini** should looks like this:

```
<form id="search_mini_form" action="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl() ?>" method="get">
<div class="form-search">
    <label for="search"><?php echo $this->__('Search:') ?></label>
    <input id="search" type="text" name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" class="input-text" maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" />
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Search')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Search') ?></span></span></button>
    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', '<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsQuoteEscape($this->__('Search entire store here...')) ?>');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getSuggestUrl() ?>', 'search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Prince, so how do I translate the default Magento Search entire store here... the phrase that appears in the Search Box.....

Comment: Look my update please

Comment: So it has $this->__('Search entire store here...'), which was the main reason why i went for this option: staging/app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/locale/pl_PL/translate.csv. So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The path is correct then inside you put this : `"Search entire store here...","The translate here..."` then flush the cache

Comment: I have done that. Still no luck :(

Comment: it's not possible i tested it and it works, are you sure that your language ISO is `pl_PL` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63161/discussion-between-user2531490-and-prince).

Comment: Try exactly this one `app/design/frontend/your package/your theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv` then put this: "Search entire store here...","Hey..."

Comment: This path app/design/frontend/your package/your theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv is meant for the us store front. But I am trying to translate the polish store front.

Comment: yes i know, it's just for testing

Comment: Looks like something is wrong somewhere because i can't even change the text on this file: app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml

Comment: Thanks for your time Prince. I just found out that the Store was using a Search Extension, so all these while we have been looking at the wrong file.

Comment: ah ok, you are using a custom extension so It's the same principle

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped you , so that other people will benefit from the answer